# Array into Database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I've been looking for awnsers for hours now, and I'm not able to figure it out. 
What I have is an Array that I want put into a database

```
if(isset($_POST['newvalue']))
            {
                $array = $_POST['newvalue'];
                $getcatidquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories_to_sales WHERE sales_id = $saleid");

                foreach($array as $value) {
                    while($getcatid = mysql_fetch_assoc($getcatidquery)) { 
                        $catid = $getcatid['categories_id'];
                    }
                    mysql_query("UPDATE categories_to_sales SET value = '$value' WHERE sales_id = '$saleid' AND categories_id = '$catid'");
                }

                echo "Executed a Query.";               
            }
```

The code above is code that's being executed when you press the submit button the update form. However this code will only update the last input in the form not all of them..

$_POST['newvalue'] is the array and I'm also able to display this array in a var_dump.

Yes, I know I'm not using PDO and I don't want to use it either because this whole system is made with mysql and the company is not going to update their PHP version. (I'm only saying this because last time those were the only comments I got on my code.)

The input form:

```
while($rowc = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
            {
                    echo '<br/>' . $rowc['categorie_name'] . ' - ' . $rowc['value'];
                    echo '<input type="text" class="valueField" name="newvalue[]" id="newvalue"/>';
            }

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories_to_sales
        LEFT JOIN sales ON categories_to_sales.sales_id=sales.sales_id 
        LEFT JOIN categories ON categories_to_sales.categories_id=categories.categorie_id 
        WHERE sales.sales_id = '$saleid'
        ");
```

Comment: Not clear.what do you want ?

Comment: I want to insert the array $_POST['newvalue'] into the database..

Comment: can you add the form code?

Comment: "Last time those were only comments I got on my code", you mean you already ask this or was it another question ?

Comment: I updated the post itself.

Comment: Brewal first of, why are you editing my post? This is just point whoring. The edit was useless. Also, I asked multiple questions here and sometimes people whine about the fact I use mysql. I know I can use mysqli or PDO and I'm aware of how it works. But there's no need for it here.

Comment: If you dont't want to use PDO you should at least use [mysql_real_escape](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for avoiding SQL injections.

Comment: Basically, this is a mess. Start again.

Comment: Is the input form back to front? Is the $sql that appears in mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) actually the query that appears immediately below it?

Comment: Strawberry, you're right the $sql query is auctually above the while loop to make the form. Also the form making process is above the update query.

Answer (score 2):

You can use serialize to stock php array in database :

```
$becomeString = serialize($yourArray);
```

When you want to return it as array use unserialize :

```
$returnArray = unserialize($myStringCreatedWithSerialize);
```

Check that :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: Don't put only a link. Answer must be more or less a complete answer. And as stackoverflow is in English, link to English documentation. See @Siraj-Khan answer. It's the same as you but a little better written.

Comment: I will, next time!! thx

Comment: You can edit your answer you know

Answer (score 1):

You have to execute your UPDATE statement inside of your while loop :

Change this

```
                foreach($array as $value) {
                    while($getcatid = mysql_fetch_assoc($getcatidquery)) { 
                        $catid = $getcatid['categories_id'];
                    }
                    mysql_query("UPDATE categories_to_sales SET value = '$value' WHERE sales_id = '$saleid' AND categories_id = '$catid'");
                }
```

To

```
                foreach($array as $value) {
                    while($getcatid = mysql_fetch_assoc($getcatidquery)) { 
                        $catid = $getcatid['categories_id'];
                        mysql_query("UPDATE categories_to_sales SET value = '$value' WHERE sales_id = '$saleid' AND categories_id = '$catid'");
                    }
                }
```

Comment: for some reason, now it only picks up the first input.

Comment: Weird : you can always echo the query to see what is executed, and check that queries are what you want and that it don't erase previous values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use serialize for inserting array in DB and unserialize using for fetch array from DB :

```
$arr = serailize($data);

$arr = unserailize($data);
```

For more detail please see :

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to get array value by `var_dump` and want to save array data into database, then best way to encode array data into string and save. When fetch data by select statement, the decode it into array format.

encode array data into string:

```
$encodedArray = json_encode($array);
```

Decode string data (encoded by json) into array:

```
$decodeArray = json_decode(MYSQL_FETCHED_VALUE, true);
```

Your can also use `serialize` and `deserialize` to save array data into database.

Hope will help!